# Unix Domain Sockets mismatch in the messages sent and received

Tags: c, sockets, client

I have created pretty basic client and server programs that use Unix-domain sockets to send messages from the server and the messages are captured by the client

The problem that I am receiving is that I am not able to capture all the messages sent from the server on the client-side

This is my server-side code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define NAME "uds_socket"
#define DATA "Test Message"
char buf[1024];

int createAndBindSocket() {
    int server_socket;
    struct sockaddr_un server_address;

    unlink(NAME);

    server_socket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_socket == -1) {
        perror("Socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else printf("Socket creation successful\n");

    int reuse = 1;
    if (setsockopt(server_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse)) == -1) perror("Error : ");
    else printf("Socket options set\n");

    server_address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(server_address.sun_path, NAME);

    if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) == -1) {
        perror("Binding failed");
        close(server_socket);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        printf("Socket binding successful with name %s\n", server_address.sun_path);
    }

    if (listen(server_socket, 5) == -1) {
        perror("Listening failed");
        close(server_socket);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else printf("Listening ...\n");

    return server_socket;
}

int handleClientRequest(int server_socket) {
    int client_socket;
    client_socket = accept(server_socket, 0, 0);
    if(client_socket == -1) {
        perror("Accepting failed");
        close(server_socket);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        printf("Connected to client\n");
    }
    return client_socket;
}

void sendMessage(int client_socket) {
    char* buf = malloc(12);
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        snprintf(buf, 12, "Hello %d", i);
        if (send(client_socket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0) < 0) {
            perror("writing on stream socket");
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Sending message ...\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
    int server_socket = createAndBindSocket();
    while(1) {
        int client_socket = handleClientRequest(server_socket);
        sendMessage(client_socket);
        close(client_socket);
    }
    unlink(NAME);
    close(server_socket);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is my client-side code

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DATA "Test Message"
char buf[1024];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int client_socket;
    struct sockaddr_un server_address;
    char buf[1024];

    client_socket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (client_socket == -1) {
        perror("Socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    server_address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(server_address.sun_path, argv[1]);

    if (connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) < 0) {
        perror("Connection failed");
        close(client_socket);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }    
    else {
        printf("Fetching message ...\n");
        int rval;
        while(1) {
            rval = recv(client_socket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
            if(rval < 0) {
                perror("Error reading message\n");
                break;
            }
            else if(rval == 0) {
                printf("Ending connection\n");
                break;
            }
            else {
                printf("%s\n", buf);
            }
        }

    }

    close(client_socket);
}
```

I am expecting the output on the client-side to be something like

```
Fetching message ...
Hello 0
Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 3
Hello 4
Ending connection
```

But the client-side output is different every time I run the programs. i.e. I do get the desired output at times, but often I get something like

```
Fetching message ...
Hello 0
Hello 1
Hello 3
Hello 4
Ending connection
```

wherein some messages are missing. Why is this so and how to resolve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> … some messages are missing. Why is this so and how to resolve it

Actually, this is not so. When using `SOCK_STREAM` there is no guarantee that you receive the data in the same pieces you sent; for example, you can well receive multiple send-pieces with one recv-call, like `"Hello 0\0Hello 1\0Hello 2\0Hello 3\0"...`, and you print only the initial piece, which causes the misconception that the others were missing. One way to resolve this is using `SOCK_SEQPACKET` instead (on server-side and client-side).

Also note that `sizeof(buf)` is certainly not the length you want to send, since it is the size of the pointer; more appropriate would be `strlen(buf)`.